# Realizar seguimiento de eventos

Tags: vb6, visual-basic

Estoy intentando seguir la depuración de un programa en este lenguaje, pero hay eventos que no logro pasar por dentro de ellos mediante la ejecución instrucción a instrucción.

¿Hay alguna manera de saber en VB 6.0 mediante su IDE o mediante cualquier otra forma en qué punto del programa estoy?

Es un programa ya con una cierta complejidad y con bastantes eventos. Sobre todo con los que más complicado es es con los que dibujan los controles en la pantalla.

Quedo agradecido de antemano por vuestros aportes.

Saludos.

Comment: Hoy en día, seguir un flujo de ejecución puede servir con porciones específicas de código o con programas cuya ejecución es totalmente lineal. Cuando quieres hacer debug a programas con interfaces de usuario ya es mucho más complicado con este enfoque, por lo que se suele optar por poner puntos de interrupción dónde busquemos analizar puntualmente , o directamente generar líneas de debug con `debug.print` y luego analizar este flujo.

Comment: Claro Patricio, esa parte la tengo controlada. El problema es que no sé en qué orden se realizan los eventos y voy dando palos de ciego. Era por saber si había o literatura sobre el tema en cuestión o si era factible el seguimiento de alguna forma desde el IDE de VB6 o cualquier opción compatible con él.